# SAS: Passing a date in macro parameter to oracle as a filter

Tags: oracle, sas

I am trying to create a macro program that iterates over a dataset in Oracle and filters on the publish_yr_mth variable and publish date. So I would have a publish date of something like 201001 (Jan 2010) and then publish_dt>01-JAN-2010. And then move to the next set of dates (but not always at even intervals, just whatever is set in the dataset).

When I create the macro, it will work with the publish_yr_mnth, but I cannot even just put in a string for the publish_dt or the macro won't run. How do I pass  a date that's readable to Oracle in this macro . Outside of macros, the 'DD-MON-YYYY' is being accepted as the correct format and will bring back a result.

Or is there something else causing this not to run?

non-marco version that will run:

```
proc sql ;

connect to oracle as mydb(user=user orapw="&dbpass" path=oracledb );

create table bk_samp as select * from connection to mdb (

     select author ,title from books_db where publish_dt >=’01-JAN-2010’ and publish_yr_mnth=201001  ) ;

quit;
```

Macro-version I want to run:

```
data months;
input publishdt publish_yr_mnth;
datalines ;
201001 01-JAN-2010
201002 02-FEB-2010
201005 02-MAY-2010
;

proc sql ;
select distinct publishdt
into: publishdt1-
from months;
quit


%macro books(publishdt, publish_yr_mnth): 
%do i =1 %to &sqlobs; proc sql ; 
connect to oracle as mydb(user=user orapw="&dbpass" path=oracledb );
 create table bk_samp as select * from connection to mdb (
      select author ,title from books_db where publish_dt >=&&publishdt&i and publish_yr_mnth=&&publishyrmth&i
 ) ;
 quit; 
%end; 
%mend books
%books();
```

I have tried passing the oracle date as a string and different date characters, even just hardcoding it without the parameter in the macro, but if I have the publish_dt condition in the macro, nothing runs.

Comment: Your example data step will not work.  You cannot read a string with letters into a numeric variable without using an informat.  Your proposed macro makes no sense.  Why have the %DO loop when the result is just same as only running it for the last value?

Comment: You can create a temporary table in ORACLE that is a copy of `months` data set and perform an ORACLE side date-based join between `books_db` and the temporary table.

Answer (score 1):

Make the macro take as input just the one set of values.  If ORACLE needs strings lik `'dd-MON-yyy'` for one for the fields then pass that into the macro.

```
%macro books(publishdt, publish_yr_mnth, outds): 
proc sql;
connect to oracle as mydb(user=user orapw="&dbpass" path=oracledb );
create table &outds as select * 
  from connection to mdb (
    select author ,title
    from books_db
    where publish_dt >=&publishdt
      and publish_yr_mnth= &publishyrmth
   ) 
;
quit; 
%mend books;
```

Then call it once for each observation in your driver table.

```
data months;
  input publishdt publish_yr_mnth :date.;
  format publish_yr_mnth date9.;
datalines ;
201001 01-JAN-2010
201002 02-FEB-2010
201005 02-MAY-2010
;

data _null_;
  set months;
  call execute(cats('%nrstr(%books)(
              ,'publishdt=',publishdt 
              ,',publish_yr_mnth=',quote(put(publish_yr_mnth,date11.),"'")
              ,',outds=temp',_n_
              ,')'
  ));
run;
```